# Tensorflow 1 and 2 Syntax Difference

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am currently taking a Coursera deep learning course and the given Tensorflow code is written in Tensorflow 1 syntax (uses session) and I havent been able to find how to rewrite it to work with Tensorflow 2.

It is really simple code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

y_hat = tf.constant(36, name='y_hat')
y = tf.constant(39, name='y')

loss = tf.Variable((y-y_hat)**2, name='loss')

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(init)
    print(session.run(loss))
```

Where can I find some guide on MANUAL syntax translation between Tensorflow 1 and 2? And would anyone be able to rewrite the given code to work with Tensorflow 2 (use functions instead of sesion) as I am quite new to Tensorflow?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you add the errors it's throwing as well as some info on what is the desired behaviour?

Comment: checkout this https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate

Comment: @nickthefreak creates 2 constant tensors and a variable tensor (whose value is the square difference between the 2 constants). Then prints value of variable tensor

Comment: @Abitbol they say "Every v1.Session.run call should be replaced by a Python function." but not how the function should look like. I saw this page but I dont know how to do what they say. They dont give examples about this step.

Comment: Just normal python code. The goal of tensorflow 2 eager mode is to get rid of previously horrible boiler plate code, you should be able to write simple python code without adding some tensorflow weirdness (in theory).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In tensorflow 2.0 you can just write your code as

```
y_hat = tf.constant(36)
y = tf.constant(39)

loss = tf.Variable((y-y_hat)**2)

print(loss.numpy())
```

It's very pythonic and the eager execution is enabled by default

Suppose you are training a model and then there is custom function which is you want to call at each iterations,now you can do this efficiently by putting `@tf.function()` before the function

[check out this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/performance)